# longtable as tabularx

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, longtabu

I want to use longtable as tabularx, that is setting the width of the table and using the X cell type.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\footnotesize}L{5.7cm}|>{\footnotesize}L{6cm}|>{\footnotesize}C{1.7cm}|>{\footnotesize}X|}
```

I want something similar but with longtable as the table is extending multiple pages.

I have found tabu package but it seems that it is deprecated and people is advicing not to use it.

Any help

Comment: in preamble add package `ltablex`. For example see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368444/my-table-is-too-wide-for-my-page-how-can-i-make-text-wrap-on-specific-columns (answer in addendum).

Comment: you could use ltablex or ltxtable both of which combine tabularx and longtable, but really, I wouldn't. You do not need the complication of tabularx here you can simply calculate the width of your last column by subtracting the widths of the other columns from \textwidth

Comment: but the tabcolsep... how do I deal with it?

Comment: you know how many columns you have and each has two `\tabcolsep` so the last column is `p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth-5.7cm-6cm-1.7cm}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I like the idea. How can I set it like a formula for automatic calculation. Let's see it as a variable argument list of lenghts and then the size is automatically calculated

Comment: I don't manage to create something like \cola \colb with the sizes and replace it in the expression you put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @DavidCarlisle suggestion, here is my solution:

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcount\totalcol
\totalcol=3
\newdimen\cola
\cola=10cm
\newdimen\colb
\colb=2cm
\newdimen\colc
\colc=\dimexpr\textwidth-\tabcolsep*\totalcol*2-\arrayrulewidth*(1+\totalcol)-\cola-\colb\relax

\begin{longtable}{|L{\cola}|C{\colb}|L{\colc}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\large\textbf{My Title}}\\
\hline
\centering\small{A} & \centering\small{B} & \centering\arraybackslash\small{C}\\
\hline
\endhead
\vspace{10pt}\\
\hline
\endfoot
%\input{data/books}

\end{longtable}
```

There problably should be an automated way of doing it, but it worked for me.